# How to make a lower class call a method of its parent?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, callback, function-pointers

I have followed this turorial [Qt Creator + OpenGL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nzHSkY4K18&t=3s) and everything is going well.

I have added a `QPlainTextEdit` on top of the `Quit` button and I would like to have `GLWidget` send info back to `MainWindow`.

How can I make `GLWidget` call a function of the `MainWindow`?

Here is some code:

// GLWidget.h

```
class GLWidget: public QGLWidget
{
Q_OBJECT // <----- 
public:
    GLWidget(QWidget* parent = 0);
    QWidget* parentObject;
    void writeText( QString );
    void (*p)(QString) = NULL;
protected:
    virtual void initializeGL();
    virtual void paintGL();
    virtual void resizeGL(int w, int h);

private:
    QTimer timer;
signals:
    //void writeText( QString );
    void dataReady(QString data); // <------------------
};
```

// GLWidget.cpp

```
GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget* parent) : QGLWidget() /7 <---- new error
{
    connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateGL()));
    timer.start(16);


    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText(typeid(parent).name());
    msgBox.exec();



    //p = parent->
    //parentObject->
    //parent->
    //parent->
    //this->parentObject = parent;
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL(){
    //emit GLWidget::dataReady("myData"); //<--------- error
    emit this->dataReady("Joe");//<--------- same as above
    glClearColor(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
}
```

// MainWindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    void print(QString text);

private slots:
    void on_plainTextEdit_textChanged();
    void foo(QString data); // <----------------------
}
```

// mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->widget->p = &MainWindow::print; // error, how to asign pointer?
}

void MainWindow::print(QString text){
    ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(text);
}

void MainWindow::foo(QString data) { // <---------
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("hi, there");
    msgBox.exec();
    // Do something with the data
    ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(data);
}
```

error:

- undefined reference to `vtable for GLWidget'
- undefined reference to `GLWidget::dataReady(QString)'

Comment: Calling for a `new Ui::MainWindow` inside a `MainWindow` constructor seems... Unlikely to be right.

Comment: @Nathan Pierson, QT creator did that itself.

Comment: define "trigger function". Do you want send a signal? nothing to do with C++, read signal\slot doc on site, it explained well. You can connect signal from child to a slot in main window, if you wish.

Comment: @Swift - Friday Pie, i have edited the code. to show what i'm doing.

Comment: `&MainWindow::print;` is not compatible with `void (*p)(QString)`, it  can be compatible with `void (MainWindow::*p)(QString)`. This is not really related to Qt, just C++ rules. You indeed have to learn C++ first, Qt next, because Qt requires a certain degree of understanding how it works  in advanced cases without knowing anything but code you can see and documentation.

Comment: @Swift - Friday Pie, it can't or can?

Comment: @NaturalDemon  if your code provided  `p` is `void (*)(QString)`. In error message it is `void (GLWidget::*)(QString)` neither is compatible. `&MainWindow::printPointer` is  `something (MainWindow::*)(something)`, a pointer to member of MainWindow.  Pointers to members are specific to the class and can be called only using an instance of that class or convertible class, with `.*` or `->*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer to your immediate question, *How to make a lower class exploit a function in it's parent?*:

All `QObject` subclasses hold a reference to their parent object, accessible through the [`parent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#parent) method.

1. Include the header of the parent's class, e.g `Foo.h`
2. Call the `parent()` methodd to obtain a pointer to the object's parent
3. Check if the pointer is valid (not a `nullptr`)
4. Cast the pointer to the parent's class, e.g. `Foo`
5. Call the desired method, e.g. `foo`

In code it looks like this:

```
#include "Foo.h"

...

if (parent())
    static_cast<Foo *>(parent())->foo();
```

That being said, this creates a tight coupling between the parent and the child and I strongly advise to avoid doing it if possible. In your case would be much better to use signals and slots to communicate the data from the child to the parent:

1. Define a signal in the child, e.g. `dataReady(DataType data)`
2. In the parent, when you create the child, connect this signal to the method, which will use the data, e.g. `foo`
3. In the child, `emit` the signal, whenever you feel like calling `foo`

In code it looks like this:

**Child.h**

```
...
signals:
    void dataReady(DataType data);
...
```

**Child.cpp**

```
...
// I want to call foo
emt dataReady(myData);
...
```

**Parent.h**

```
...
private slots:
    void foo(DataType data);
...
```

**Parent.cpp**

```
...
//somewhere
auto *child = new Child(...);
connect(child, &Child::dataReady, this, &Parent::foo);

...

void Parent::foo(DataType data) {
    // Do something with the data
    ...
}
...
```

This requires more work initially, but it is much better in a long-term.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222753/discussion-on-answer-by-user6528273-how-to-make-a-lower-class-call-a-method-of-i).